# Identify the arguments, parameters, local variables and global variables used in the following code?

Tags: javascript, parameters, arguments, global-variables, local-variables

The code is:

```
var x = 32;
var y = 44;
var radius = 5;
var centerX = 0;
var centerY = 0;
var width = 600;
var height = 400;

function setup(width, height) {
  centerX = width/2;
  centerY = height/2;
}

function computeDistance(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  var dx = x1 - x2;
  var dy = y1 - y2;
  var d2 = (dx * dx) + (dy * dy);
  var d = Math.sqrt(d2);
  return d;
}

function circleArea(r) {
  var area = Math.PI * r * r;
  return area;
}

setup(width, height);

var area = circleArea(radius);
var distance = computeDistance(x, y, centerX, centerY);

alert("Area: " + area);
alert("Distance: " + distance);
```

Also, Which local variable(s) shadows the global variable(s)?

**My answer**

Arguments: width, height, radius, x, y, centerX, centerY, “Area: ” + area, “Distance: ”+ distance, d2.

Parameters: width, height, x1, y1, x2, y2, r

Local Variables: dx, dy, d2, d, area*

Global Variables: x, y, radius, centerX, centerY, width, height, area, distance

*area shadows the Global variable area.

**But in the book answer**: d2 was not given as an argument, maybe there forgot it or something... I want to know whether my answer is correct.

Comment: Well, I’d say that in the line `var d2 = (dx * dx) + (dy * dy);` `d2` is declared as a variable and in the line `var d = Math.sqrt(d2);` it’s passed as an argument.

Comment: See if the book has an errata somewhere on the web. Otherwise your answers are right. Except  local variable "area" doesn't shadow the global variable "area". inside the function circleArea() it has its own scope but that scope is unavailable outside that function. Also the global variable "area" can still be accessible inside the function if you use window.area - just an idea.

Comment: Thanks Andy, so what do you think my answer is correct??

Comment: Harish Thanks mate but the book also shows that local variable area shadows Global variable area, So are you 100% sure???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer looks correct. The book may just have been looking for the arguments, parameters, and variables from of the functions defined on the page. It seems you out-smarted them. You could perhaps submit it to them as a correction because your answer is technically correct.